# Adding a driver to device path UEFI

Tags: c, filter, driver, bios, uefi

I am trying to add a filter driver to a protocol in UEFI, meaning that everyone who consumes the protocol, in the hierarchy, will eventually pass through me.

I understand I need to add my driver to the relevant device path - though no idea how. More than that, how will it work with any handles that are already connected to the device?
(If I understood correctly, I need to connect my driver to the device using BY_DRIVER | EXCLUSIVE, and once I connect my own driver to the device path and use ConnectController with my driver handles, the UEFI should automatically connect any supporting handles to me).

I am hoping if anyone knows how to add a driver that would act as a filter driver (or in a different semantic - layer driver?) for a specific protocol.

Would really, **really** appreciate any given help, since I have not found any help anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It's not complicated. The only thing you need to do is reinstall the protocols which you wanna intercept.

Let's take EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL as an example:

1. Collect all PCI device handles in handle database: `LocateHandleBuffer()`
2. Get the original PCI IO interface on each handle by `HandleProtocol()`, record it somewhere as you may want to call it inside your new protocol interface.
3. Reinstall PCI IO Protocol by `gBS->ReinstallProtocolInterface`, which will disconnect the device and replace the old protocol interface with the new one.